# Numpy ufunc 'equal' did not contain a loop with signature matching types

Tags: python, numpy

I'm trying to search for instances of a given value in a numpy array using `np.equal()`, example:

```py
a = ["192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.2", "192.168.0.3"]
b = "192.168.0.3"

a = np.array(a, dtype=str)
b = np.array(b, dtype=str)

result = np.equal(a,b)
```

But when `np.equal()` goes to search for `b` in the `a` array, I get the error in the title. I've come across this mistake when testing a script in a production environment with numpy 1.21.6, it does not happen on the testing environment with numpy 1.24.2.

Besides updating the numpy on the production server (may break other stuff), how do I solve this?

Full error:

```py
numpy.core._exceptions.UFuncTypeError: ufunc 'equal' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (dtype('<U1'), dtype('<U1')) -> dtype('bool')
```

I've tried to force the `dtype` for both arrays with `dtype=str` in the array definition. I've also read other questions but didn't find anything similar.

Comment: `U11`, `U31` are both `str` dtypes.

Answer (score 0):

If you're OK with the potential performance hit, the following code works on 1.21.6:

```
import numpy as np
a = ["192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.2", "192.168.0.3"]
b = "192.168.0.3"

a = np.array(a)

result = a == b
print(result)
```

yields

```
[False False  True]
```

In newer versions of numpy, I'm seeing the following two statements take about the same amount of time, about 0.29s, but on 1.21.6, the first statement takes about 5.44s, so it might matter if you're running with 10k IPs 500 times.

```
a = [".".join(map(str,np.random.randint(256,size=4))) for _ in range(10000)]
print(timeit.timeit('sum(a == b)', globals=globals(), number=500))
print(timeit.timeit('sum(np.equal(a,b))', globals=globals(), number=500))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you can do some pre-processing, all IPv4 addresses are really 32-bit integers, which are *much* cleaner and likely faster to work with

```py
from ipaddress import ip_address
a = ["192.168.0.1", "192.168.0.2", "192.168.0.3"]
b = "192.168.0.3"

# convert to numeric equivalent
a = [int(ip_address(ip)) for ip in a]
b = int(ip_address(b))

a = np.array(a)  # detected as int64, may be worth making int32
b = np.array(b)

result = np.equal(a,b)
```

```py
>>> result
array([False, False,  True])
>>> a
array([3232235521, 3232235522, 3232235523])
>>> list(map(ip_address, map(int, a)))  # can't convert numpy type directly
[IPv4Address('192.168.0.1'), IPv4Address('192.168.0.2'), IPv4Address('192.168.0.3')]
```