# Why doesn't "np.equal" (Numpy) work for me when executing under PyCharm?

Tags: python, numpy, pycharm

I'm trying to understand some curious behavior running Python **under PyCharm**.
Here's the code:

```
import numpy as np
s="aabaaaacaabc"
m=np.array( [ list( s ) ] * 3 )
print("m", m )
l=np.array([['a'],['b'],['c']] )
print( "l", l )
x = np.equal( m, l )
```

and here's what I get when I execute it:

```
C:\Users\marka\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\python3.10.exe "C:\Users\marka\Leet Notebooks\.ipynb_checkpoints\NumpyQuestion.py" 
m [['a' 'a' 'b' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'c' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'c']
 ['a' 'a' 'b' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'c' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'c']
 ['a' 'a' 'b' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'a' 'c' 'a' 'a' 'b' 'c']]
l [['a']
 ['b']
 ['c']]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\marka\Leet Notebooks\.ipynb_checkpoints\NumpyQuestion.py", line 7, in <module>
    x = np.equal( m, l )
numpy.core._exceptions._UFuncNoLoopError: ufunc 'equal' did not contain a loop with signature matching types (<class 'numpy.dtype[str_]'>, <class 'numpy.dtype[str_]'>) -> None

Process finished with exit code
```

The reason I say "curious" is because this code runs correctly
when run on my non-PyCharm Python interpreter.  Is there something
funky about PyCharm that's causing this?

Comment: Are the versions of Python and numpy the same between your PyCharm and non-PyCharm interpreters? (For example, see this similar question where an error occurs on numpy 1.21.6 but not on 1.24.2 - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76633016/numpy-ufunc-equal-did-not-contain-a-loop-with-signature-matching-types)

Comment: I get the same outcome both in Anaconda and system Python (not using PyCharm). The error simply says it has no implemented operator for comparing strings. Maybe you have some different Python and NumPy version outside your PyCharm, which has this functionality implemented.

Comment: Thanks for both responses.   Yes, indeed, my PyCharm seems to be using v3.10.... and my Python interpreter is v3.11...   However, I'm pretty sure that the dtypes of the two operands agree ("<U1") and I would think np.equal is not new to v3.11.   Curious, no?

Comment: Those are the Python versions, but what about numpy? Try adding `print(np.__version__)` to your script and you can check.

Comment: Definitely numpy version.  Seems to fail in 1.21 and work in 1.24.

Comment: @MarkLavin what is the version of *numpy*? The Python version probably isn't really relevant (unless it was a 2/3 thing)

Comment: In PyCharm, where the code is failing, numpy version is 1.22.4    In my Python interpreter, where the numpy version is 1.24.2, the code works.   All this seems to point to numpy as the culprit.   Does anyone know how I could update the version of numpy being used by PyCharm?

Comment: Found out how to update PyCharm's numpy package to 1.26; all now works.  Thanks to everyone for your comments.